# XElement.Elements(XName) method unable to read xml nodes having attributes

Tags: c#, wpf, xml, linq-to-xml, xelement

I am trying to filter the xmldata using Linq to Xml,the problem is i am not able to get the elements using XElement.Elements(Xname) method but when working with XElement.Desendents(Xname) method it works fine but displays all the element which i don`t want. What i want it it should displays all the  element and attributes,whose element and attribute name is  passed in the two textboxes.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?> 
<Summary AvailableRules="71000" SelectedRules="445" OmittedRules="6887">
  <BBCE AvailableRules="69" SelectedRules="4" OmittedRules="65">
    <SelectedRules>
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0201" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0211" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0221" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0231" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
    </SelectedRules>
    <OmittedRules>
      <Rule RuleID="ar_0001" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="ar_0002" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0143_a" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0143_b" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0311" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0321" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0331" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0341" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0011" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0021" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="na_0004_a" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="na_0004_b" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0043" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0042" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="na_0005" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0081" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jm_0002" Priority="Mandatory" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0142" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0061" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0146" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0140" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jm_0013" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0032" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="db_0141" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0171" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jm_0010" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="jc_0281" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="na_0008" Priority="Recommended" /> 
      <Rule RuleID="na_0009" Priority="Strongly Recommended" /> 
    </OmittedRules>
  </BBCE>
</Summary>
```

C# code:

```
var button = sender as Button;
var parent = button.Parent as FrameworkElement;

//(Textbox to take element`s name)
var textBox = parent.FindName("textbox1") as TextBox;

var textbl = parent.FindName("abc") as TextBlock;
var com = parent.FindName("cbox1") as ComboBox;

//(Textbox to take ATTRIBUTE`s name)  
var textBox1 = parent.FindName("textbox2") as TextBox;

XElement ele = XElement.Load(txtFileName.Text);

//working with Xelement.desendents it works fine
var fil = from item in ele.Elements(textbl.Text)
          select item.Element(textBox.Text).Attribute(textBox1.Text);

foreach (var f in fil)
{
    Label lb = new Label();
    lb.Content = f;
    canvas1.Children.Add(lb);
}
```

What I observed was when working with only BBCE element it works fine,but on adding Summary element with attribute (Elements method) won`t work.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Elements(name)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348975.aspx) method returns child elements of node. [Descendants(name)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360635.aspx) method returns descendant elements of node. Thats expected behavior.

So, when you are calling `ele.Elements(textbl.Text)` then search will occur only between direct children of `ele` elements. When you are loading file via `XElement ele = XElement.Load`, then `ele` element will be root element of xml. I.e. `<Summary>` element in your case. It has single child `<BBCE>`. That's why you can find only `<BBCE>` when you are using `Elements()` method to search.

`Descendants()` method in your case will search for any element in document, except `<Summary>` node itself.